# Wordpress Plugin Add New Page

Tags: wordpress

I have a created a wordpress plugin that needs to create a page dynamically.

When the plugin is activated a page is created COOKIE_POLICY.

From my reading I found that inserting into the DB is the best way. And below is the way to do it. However, when I activate the plugin, there is no page or post created.

I go this from:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

```
function create_policy() {

  $my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['COOKIE_POLICY'] ),
  'post_content'  => $_POST['Here is all our cookie policy info'],
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 8,30 )
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_policy' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is nearly correct. Below is the fixed code

```
 function create_policy() {

 $my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'cookiepolicy',
  'post_content'  => 'this is my content',
  'post_type'     => 'page',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array( 3,4 )
  );

  // Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'create_policy' );
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot